# How do I detect the input of a thumbstick on a VR headset? (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculusquest

I am creating a VR game in unity. To make the player run, I am making the player press the left thumbstick down. How am I able to detect the press and release of the thumbstick?

I have tried using action maps, but I could not find a way to detect releasing the thumbstick using an action map. I have also tried this :

```
void Update() {
        bool active;
        if (leftDevice.TryGetFeatureValue(UnityEngine.XR.CommonUsages.primary2DAxisClick, out active) && active) {
            moveProvider.moveSpeed = runSpeed;
        } else {
            moveProvider.moveSpeed = walkSpeed;
        }
    }
```

This did not make the player run at all.

Answer (score 0):

**Add this script to your GameObject as a component and set the button and events from the inspector**

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class OnButtonPress : MonoBehaviour
{

    public InputAction action = null;

    // When the button is pressed
    public UnityEvent OnPress = new UnityEvent();

    // When the button is released
    public UnityEvent OnRelease = new UnityEvent();

    private void Awake()
    {
        action.started += Pressed;
        action.canceled += Released;
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        action.started -= Pressed;
        action.canceled -= Released;
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        action.Enable();
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        action.Disable();
    }

    private void Pressed(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        OnPress.Invoke();
    }

    private void Released(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        OnRelease.Invoke();
    }
}
```